# Extend a list with another one. Why this behaviour?

Tags: python, list, extend

I have a 2 elements list which I want to extend with the elements of another one.
playing around in Jupyter I found this strange behaviour that I can not understand.

```
# this is my first list
columnslist=['app','SUM']
['app','SUM']

# it is going to be extended with the values A and B

columnslist.extend(['A','B'])
['app','SUM','A','B']

# It is possible to make a list out of a string in this way
print(list('AB'))
['A','B']

# I realise that list('AB')= ['A','B']
This works:
columnslist.extend(list('AB'))

# but the following does not work:
mytext='this is a text to be split'
columnslist.extend(mytext.split())
```

why is that so? 
thanks

Comment: Where have you seen `list[...]` and why do you feel this is more correct than the `list(...)` syntax you used  just one line above?

Comment: thanks. that was a typo

Comment: `list['AB']` is not the correct syntax IMHO. `list(['AB'])`

Comment: You fixed the "typo" with something more incorrect.

Comment: typos corrected. What I see is that list gets a string into () and gives a list which elements are the characters of the string. @cph: in list(['AB']) you are passing to list a list, since ['AB'] is a list with one element. list(['AB']) gives ['AB'] and not 'A', 'B'.

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? What are you expecting instead?

Comment: `list('AB')` gets an iterable as an argument; the iterable contains two 1-character strings `'A'` and `'B'`. `list(['AB'])` *also* gets an iterable as an argument; that iterable contains a single 2-character string `'AB'`. `['AB']` has an extra layer of iteration compared to `'AB'`; it's an iterable that contains an iterable.

Comment: by mytext='this is a text to be split'


columnslist.extend(mytext.split())


I would expect 

columnslist=['app','SUM','A','B', 'this','is','a','text','to','be','split']

Answer (score -1):

First thing it's bad practice to use keywords as variable. Second thing it can't make use of extend function since it's a dictionary object.

Edit:
I hope that i am guessing it right, you want to extract alphabet in a string with whitespaces? then you can try following code

```
>>>my_list= ["A","B"]
>>>test_str = "This is a text"
>>>my_list.extend(list("".join(test_str.split())))
['A','B','T', 'h', 'i', 's', 'i', 's', 'a', 't', 'e', 'x', 't']
```

Comment: Gaurav, this is just an example. And I am quite beginner.

Comment: Its okay. If my tones sound harsh sorry for that. I am just explaining in short. Keep going

Comment: Anyway, a wind blowed the question and low vote all. Nevertheless the last issue is not solved yet.

Comment: ahh that's always happen when its stackoverflow, you want to extract alphabet of string am i right?

Answer (score -1):

The text is separated by space, you can use `.split` here. `.split` converts a string in a list.

```
columnslist.extend(mytext.split(' '))
```

Comment: `split` with no argument already splits on whitespace; this doesn't really add anything.